# Pyspark: how to filter rows for multiple criteria?

Tags: pyspark

Say i have a dataset such as this
[image]
| game_name | developer_name |
| --------  | -------------- |
|  X        |  John          |
|  Y        | Mark            |[![enter image description here][2]][2]
|  X        | Mark |
|  Z        | John           |
|  Y         | John|
How do i find the list of all game_name s that two developers both worked on (eg:all game names that both John and Mark worked on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupby` the `game_name` col and then `list` the `developer_name` column

```
df.groupby(['game_name'])['developer_name'].apply(list).reset_index()
```